# Running Reporting Services against a test database

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

What's the best way to setup SSRS reports to run against a test database?  We need  to run them from the Report Server (e.g. from a browser) against a test database.  I tried creating a linked report but I don't see a way to associate a different data connection with the linked report.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually create a second copy of reports in a Test folder on the SSRS server. This lets consumers test report changes before they affect production.

But if you really want one version of the report to point at both production and test you can get clever with data sources. Here's a blog entry discussing dynamically changing your datasource based on a parameter.
http://skamie.wordpress.com/2010/12/17/ssrs-changing-data-source-dynamically/

Then you'll need to either expose the parameter or call the report in some way where you can set the hidden parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new folder in the Report Manager and upload the exact same report to that new folder.
If needed, you can also hide this folder so only testing people can access the URL directly.

Create a new data source that points to your test database and change the data source of the new report to use the test data source.

That way you can leave your production report intact.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Properties > Data Sources and point the datasource to your test database

Comment: I mean while leaving the production report still pointing at production.  Is the only way to deploy a second report for testing?